# Speed of a car on a highway

Tags: self-study, distributions, modeling

I am working on the following problem:

> On a long drive from Columbus to Cleveland, you realize that you are passing more cars than are passing you. After counting for some period of time, you find that you have passed 90 cars while having been passed only 10 times. Assuming the average speed on the freeway is 75, how fast are you traveling? Apart from assuming that each car travels at a constant speed, you can make any further assumptions you feel are useful (e.g., the value of the speed limit, the length of time over which you were counting, etc).

I started by assuming a normal distribution on the speeds of the cars (there will be very few cars that are too slow or too fast, and a large number of cars will be close to the average speed) with $\mu = 75$. Assuming $\sigma=5$, and by looking up the standard normal distribution $z$ table, we find that for $z=1.28$, area under the curve is $0.8997\approx 90\%$. Using $x=z\sigma+\mu$, we have $x=81.4$ (with the above assumptions).

It seemed all nice and elegant to me till it was pointed out that the *observer* in the question is in the moving car, while the observer in my solution is standing by the side of the road, or taking an aerial view - basically an outside observer. Due to this, my solution goes down the drain.

Any suggestion on what distribution would work in this case? Or any other other approaches to solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hint: What changes in your calculations when you shift to the in-car point of view? (Answer: nothing that matters.)